# React on rails:Iterating through an array of activerecord

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, react-rails

I am new to React with Rails and use of `react-rails` gem.

I am trying to loop through all lifts and show the liftname through Lift component.

The controller action index provides:

```
class LiftsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @lifts = Lift.all
    end
end
```

Under `assets/javascripts/components` I have a lift.js.jsx component.

```
class Lifts extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const arr = {this.props.data}.map((x) => <li>Hello {x.liftname}!</li>);
    return (<ul>{arr}</ul>);    
  }
}
```

In the view page, I am passing the data as shown below:

```
<%= react_component('Lifts', data: @lifts) %>
```

But, I am receiving the error:

```
SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (3:20)
  1 | class Lifts extends React.Component {
  2 |   render() {
> 3 |       const arr = {this.props.data}.map((x) => <li>Hello {x.liftname}!</li>);
    |                     ^
  4 |       return (<ul>{arr}</ul>);    
  5 |   }
  6 | }
```

My questions are:

1. Where I am going wrong
2. Is there any debugger for react which gives more info apart from unexpected token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this line should be without curly braces in the first case, like this:

```
const arr = this.props.data.map((x) => <li>Hello {x.liftname}!</li>);
```

And you also have to define the `key` prop for every `li` item otherwise React'll drop a warning.